# Git Bash Client for windows not able to clone github repository

Tags: git, bash, github

I am using git bash client on windows 10 64-bit system but when I try to clone or pull or push repositories from git hub it showing the error:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/adeptia/enigma.git/' not found
```

While  repositories are exists and I am also able to clone, pull and push these repository using eclipse or github desktop.

I can commit and check status of repository using git bash client if it cloned using eclipse or github desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have a **[credential helper](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage)** with

```
git config credential.helper
```

If you see manager, it is possible the wrong credentials are cached.
In that case, you need to remove them.
See "[Github remote permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47466980/6309)".

The other possibility is the presence of [2FA (2 factor Authentication)](https://help.github.com/articles/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa/), which would require a PTA (Personnal Access Token) in place of the regular account password.

Answer (score 0):

git clone command is > git clone https://github.com/adeptia/enigma.git/

when command not work, you confirm url accurate

if you sure url is exist or correct, we need to more information to answer

Comment: that repository exist until now?

Comment: Yes repository exists.At same time I can push commit changes using eclipse but git bash client not able to do so..

Comment: are you try to cloning private repository?

Comment: I can commit and check status of repository using git bash client if it cloned using eclipse or other tool.

Comment: This error occur for both private and public repository. I also tried after to re-install git bash client but same issue persist..

Answer (score -2):

I think cause github server having problem now, because today I can not access to github or my github repository.
You can try again later.

Comment: Its not only today issue and i am also able to do these operation using eclipse.