# Can't push to git

Tags: github

Once I had an old github account, and I'm trying to create a new one and push to that one, but I keep running into permission issues:

```
remote: Permission to <new account>/<new account>.github.io.git denied to <old username>.
```

I've tried setting the user name + password, going through different procedures to add ssh keys, deleting my .ssh folder, deleting my old repos, everything I can think of, but I can't fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check first if your URL is actually an SSH one:

```
git remote -v
```

If it is an https,... no amount of SSH setting will allow you to authenticate properly.
If it is an https (again), do check your  **[credential helper](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage)** with:

```
git config credential.helper
```

If you see `manager`, it is possible the wrong credentials are cached.
In that case, you need to remove them.
See "[Github remote permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47466980/6309)".

The other possibility is the presence of [2FA (2 factor Authentication)](https://help.github.com/articles/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa/), which would require a PTA (Personnal Access Token) in place of the regular account password.

But again, you can also switch to an SSH URL:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:auser/arepo.git
```

Comment: Ah this was it. I went into Keychain Access, deleted items related to github and it worked.

Comment: @Kevin Exactly: a credential helper is helpful... to a point ;)