# Jenkins Global Pipeline Configuration - GitHub account issue

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have been trying to configure Global Pipeline libraries in Jenkins using GitHub repo, but encountered an issue "invalid account" even though GitHub credentials are correct.
**Detailed description:**

1. GitHub API endpoint is URL: https://github.mycompanydomain/api/v3
2. I have provided Library details with Name, Default version and selected Modern SCM
3. In Modern SCM, I have selected GitHub, I am able to select API end point from dropdown but when I selected "Credentials" (I have configured this in credentials option in Jenkins with username and password which I have been used to connect gitHub), it is giving "invalid credentials".

Please find below error code image for reference.

[image]

Please help,

Regards,
Srikanth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Details:**

1. Verified System log : **[JenkinsURL]/log/all** then log shows the error:

```html
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

2. Initially imported certificate from GitHub Enterprise to \jre\lib\security\cacerts but Jenkins by default referring to jre which ships with installer. So later I have imported it to \jre\lib\security\cacerts which resolved the issue.

Thank you @VonC for your help.

Answer (score 2):

For an https URL (using a username/password type of credential), do check if the password includes any special character.

If it does, you might need to [percent encode them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Character_data).

The other possibility is if your account has [2FA (two factor authentication)](https://help.github.com/articles/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa/) activated.
If it does, the password should be a [PTA (Personnal Token Access)](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/), not your actual account password.

Third possibility (from the chat): there is a proxy.

So:

- either the client and GHE (GitHub Enterprise) are on the same LAN and Git, incorrectly, tries to go through the proxy while it shouldn't: a NO_PROXY is necessary.
- or GHE is accessible only through the proxy, and neither Git or Jenkins are aware of the proxy (HTTP_PROXY/HTTPS_PROXY environment variable should be set)

Comment: Hi VonC, Thanks for the response. I have verified on GitHub and 2FA authentication has not been configured and also password doesn't include special character

Comment: @Srikanth And I supposed your username/password is the one used for your private GitHub enterprise instance? And it is correct (not upercase/lowercase issue)?

Comment: yes my username/password is the one used for my private GitHub enterprise instance and it is correct

Comment: Under which account your Jankins is running? Is there a git crednetial helper? (git config credential.helper)?

Comment: Jenkins is running under my account and Jenkins has been installed on Windows

Comment: @Srikanth Then type `git config credential.helper` and check if it is `manager`. If it is, try and delete the github.com entry as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47466980/6309

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162564/discussion-between-srikanth-and-vonc).