# How do you setup authentication with the GitHub client?

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I am new to GitHub and have been in the process of uploading old projects to it.

Unfortunately, I have started to encounter this error whenever I want to publish more projects.

```
Requires authentication
```

This error persists even on my laptop.

If someone could help me out, that would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have followed first the [Authenticating to GitHub](https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/getting-started-with-github-desktop/authenticating-to-github/) guide: the client "GitHub Desktop" needs to know under which account it will create/push that new repository.

If it does not, then the error message would pop up.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like I needed to log off and back in. This was probably because I changed my GitHub name.

Comment: @Longurimont Check also your credential helper, in case it has cached the wrong credentials: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47466980/6309