# Permission to user1 denied to user2

Tags: github

I have following problem with gitHub
can someone help me with step by step instruction?

[image]

Comment: Your question lacks information to get any help from SO users.
Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), learn [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to maximize your chance to get answer to your questions.
If you run into a specific problem and if you're stuck, send a description of the problem, including a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and people will be very glad to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Github remote permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47465644/github-remote-permission-denied)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User1 should go to `https://github.com/USER1/THE_REPO/settings/collaboration` (replace words in caps appropriately) and add user2 as a collaborator.

Or to get there from User1's github, click on the repository, then settings, then collaborators.

Then user2 should accept the collaboration invitation on GitHub.

Comment: I did as you said but did not help.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEyB1pHEaAo&feature=youtu.be

Comment: It's "awaiting response", I updated the answer accordingly.