# Git push not working with privater repository

Tags: git

I am trying to push to a remote private repository for the first time. Please note that I was successfully able to clone as well as commit the changes I made. And I am using https protocol. But when I use the following command;

```
git push origin
```

Then I get the error; repository not found. Please note that repository exists for sure.
May I know whether I need to add my username and password to the url.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: is it on GitHub? did you use a token to clone, or user/password?

Comment: have you add your remote origin?

Comment: What does `git remote -vv` say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please note that I was successfully able to clone as well as commit the changes I made

A commit is a local operation only: you will succeed to commit, irrespective of the nature of the remote repository (private or public)

If `git remote -v` does show an HTTPS URL, check your credential helper (which might have cached the wrong credentials): `git config credential.helper`. You can clear [that credential cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47466980/6309), try and push again.