# Am unable to push my project folder to GitHub

Tags: git, github, cmd, syntax-error, git-remote

I am unable to push my project folder on my laptop to GitHub using git. This is the error it brings below after i had entered the command in the git bash 'git push -u origin master'. I also have my internet connection on

remote: permission to dlaw-code/Mama-Bili.git denied to dlàw-code.
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitHub.com/dlàw-code/Mama-Bili.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: Probably this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47466980/8370915) is related to your problem. Please, check.

Answer (score 1):

you can set a global config with this command `git config --global` `init.defaultBranch {branchName`}

Replace `{branchName}` with the default branch name and now whenever you create a new git repo, the default branch will be this.

Comment: Please how do I change from master branch to main on git

Comment: see if this helps, i done some edits